# WebStorm system font missing in Settings

Tags: jetbrains-ide

Can't find installed font (Iosevka) in the Settings `Editor > Font` view.

I'm using WebStorm **2018.3.2** - installed via *Jetbrains Toolbox* in Windows 10 1809.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the font recognize by copying it to WebStorm's installation path:

`C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\WebStorm\ch-0\183.4886.41\jre64\lib\fonts`

Not a nice solution, but it works.